# Singleton class not compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I attempt to compile below code I receive the error "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor". Im receiving the error at line `this(text, style, font, colour, backgroundBitmap);`

Im not within the constructor, im just trying to call it from an initialise method.

```
public class TimerLabelFieldSingleton extends TimerLabelField{

    private TimerLabelFieldSingleton ref;

    private TimerLabelFieldSingleton(Object text, long style, Font font,
            int colour, Bitmap backgroundBitmap) {
        super(text, style, font, colour, backgroundBitmap);
    }

    private void initialise(Object text, long style, Font font,int colour, Bitmap backgroundBitmap){
        this(text, style, font, colour, backgroundBitmap);
    }

    public TimerLabelFieldSingleton getSingletonObject(Object text, long style, Font font,int colour, Bitmap backgroundBitmap){
        if(ref == null){
            ref = new TimerLabelFieldSingleton(text, style, font,colour, backgroundBitmap);
        }
        return ref;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have just realised that initialization will occur when getSingletonObject is invoked. thanks for answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not allowed to call the constructor (or `super` constructor) from anywhere else but in the constructor it self. In other words, you cannot call `this()` from another method than the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Inside initialize you cannot call this(... or super(.... Constructors can only be called from constructors.

By looking at your code as it is now, you don't need that initialize method at all.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is precisely that the line throwing the error is not within a constructor. `this()` can only be called from a constructor.  It does not make sense to call a constructor once the object has already been constructed, so Java does not allow constructor calls outside of constructors.

I'm assuming that your `initialize` method is being called by some constructor that is not shown here.  Considering all the `initialize` method does is call a constructor, why not just do it from wherever you are calling `initialize`?

Comment: Yes, ill just call getSingletonObject.

Answer (score 2):

The `this()` syntax is only used to call another constructor *from a constructor*. Your `initialise` method is *not a constructor*.

I'm not sure what you really want to do here, but you *either* want to

- call `super.initialise()` instead of `this()` or
- do some other initialisation in your `initialise` method

Also be aware that your `initialise` method is `private` and nothing in that code calls it, so it's useless (won't ever be called).